# Delay of highlight in UIButton in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Alright so normally this problem happens in a tableView's scrollView or scrollView of some sort but I am having a "halfway delay" on a UIButton that is contained in simply a UIView. Here's my code:

```
UIButton *brightnessUpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[brightnessUpButton setFrame:CGRectMake(260, 0, 60, 144)]; //y:5 height:80
brightnessUpButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 50, 0);
UIButton *brightnessDownButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 24, 40, 40)];
[brightnessUpButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brightnessUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[brightnessUpButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brightnessUpHighlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[brightnessDownButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brightnessDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[luxView addSubview:brightnessUpButton];
[luxView addSubview:brightnessDownButton];
```

So the problem is currently with `brightnessUpButton`. As you can see I did nothing but set the frame and content Insets. So the problem is when you click on the button. If you click below where the image appears in the button you get a 1-2 second delay for the highlight of the button. If you click on the image, you get an immediate highlight, and when you click above the image of the UIButton you get an immediate highlight.

This behavior makes no sense to me because the UIButton is added to a UIView, not a scrollView of any sort and the highlighting only happens immediately with half of the button. I have tried:

> 1) setting the imageEdgeInsets and contentEdgeInsets as apprropriate
>
> 2) Using the View debugger to see if there's some additional object interfering with the button - of which the result was NONE, the UIView exists on top of the UIView and that is all.

What could possibly be causing this weird behavior?

Comment: any tap gestures added to the view ?

Comment: Yes actually. There is one that is added to self.view.